# I got this error message although every font is installed: "Error producing PDF ! LaTeX Error: File `[fontname].sty' not found"

Tags: fonts, pdf, pandoc

I am using pandoc to convert txt files to pdf. Whenever I specify a font in my metadata, I am getting the following error message, although I've checked that every font is installed:

```
% Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: File `[fontname].sty' not found. 

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

The following is my metadata in the txt file:

```
title: title
fontfamily: Libre Baskerville [or some other font]
fontsize: 10pt
margin-left: 1.5in
margin-right: 1.5in
margin-top: 1.5in
margin-bottom: 1.5in
indent: true
linestretch: 1.25
documentclass: article
```

And this is my command line in terminal:

```
pandoc test.txt -s -o test.pdf -V --pdf-engine=xelatex
```

I am using macos Ventura 13, Pandoc 3.1.2,MacTex-2023

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does the error condition persist if you replace `--pdf-engine=xelatex` with `--pdf-engine=lualatex`?

Comment: If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to access your system fonts, you need to use `mainfont` instead of `fontfamily` which is used with pdflatex and the fonts installed in you LaTeX distribution

Comment: If you specifically want to use [`Libre Baskerville`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/librebaskerville) in your LaTeX distribution (which also supports XeLaTeX), then you have to use the package name without the extension, i.e. `fontfamily: librebaskerville`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc has two font loading mechanism for latex in place:

1. Using packages installed in your latex distribution with `fontfamily`. This option mainly aims for `pdflatex` + postscript fonts, but there are packages that will also support other font formats and engines.

   Usage: `fontfamily: packagename` will attempt to load the package with `\usepackage{packagename}` and will only work, if `packagename.sty` can be found.
2. Using fonts installed on your system with `mainfont`. This option works only with `xelatex` and `lualatex` + open/true type fonts.

   Usage: `mainfont: Font Name` will attempt to load the font using [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) with `\setmainfont{Font Name}`.

More details can be found in the [manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#fonts) or directly in the [latex default template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/main/data/templates/default.latex).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now it works by following the first advice (1)! (2) is not working for me (it doesn't show up the error message, but the font produced is Latin Modern no matter which font I specify), because I guess fonts are not installed in my system. Could I ask how I can install Latex fonts in the system? Thanks again!

Comment: You just download the font files and install them like any other font. In the case of Libre Baskerville you can download them here: https://github.com/impallari/Libre-Baskerville. Or, if you use [homebrew](https://brew.sh), tap the [fonts cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-fonts) with `brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts`, and install Libre Baskerville with `brew install font-libre-baskerville`

Comment: Thanks so much! The answer is super helpful!